# updating an object in object array angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, loops

I am trying to update one particular entry in the entire array based on id value. If I try using the for loop it shows some undesired output. please let me know what can be done on this. Sample code which I tried as follows,

```
 angular.module('app').controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.object = {
        name: 'test',
        objects: [
            {id: 1, name: 'test1'},
            {id: 2, name: 'test2'}
        ]
    };

    $scope.update = function(id, data) {
        var objects = $scope.object.objects;

        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            if (objects[i].id == id) {
                objects[i].name = data;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what exact *undesired output* you are getting? Is your `data` arg in function correct?

Comment: Can you show me, where you call the update function? and are you using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Is this code supposed to update the `name` property of an object?

#### If yes

You should change this line of your for loop:

```
objects[i] = data;
```

To:

```
objects[i].name = data;
```

#### If no

You are trying to replace an object you are iterating over. It may create issues in the looping. If so, you would better to update each property instead of trying to overwrite the whole object.

Comment: did you understand this question? first understand the question and then post the answer. and if you need any clarification first ask that in comment :)

Comment: @RameshRajendran I think  I do, but I may have misunderstood. ;-P